# How to arrange this data in a crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

i have a xml data like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <supplier>
    <s_code>1</s_code>
    <net_weight>100</net_weight>
    <rate>100.00</rate>

    <items>
      <s_code>1</s_code> 
      <item_code>SKU001</items_code>
      <price>100</price>
    </items>
    <items>
      <s_code>1</s_code>
      <item_code>SKU002</items_code>
      <price>200</price>
    </items>

  </supplier>

  <supplier>
    <s_code>2</s_code>
    <net_weight>500</net_weight>
    <rate>150.00</rate>

    <items>
      <s_code>2</s_code>
      <item_code>SKU001</items_code>
      <price>100</price>
    </items>

  </supplier>

</root>
```

and this is what i did

1. Define a dataset and two tables inside it.
2. DataTable1 to store supplier data and DataTable2 to store items data
3. created nested relation between DataTable1 s_code and DataTable2 s_code
4. created a crystal report with dataset and added s_code,net_weight to header section and 
   item_code,price into details section.
5. then i right click on crystal report and selected Report->Selection Expert and set Section paging tab to New page after 1 visible record

this is the code i used to load xml into two tables

```
DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/data.xml");

DataSet dset = new DataSet1();
dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]);
dset.Tables[1].Merge(reportData.Tables[1]);

ReportDocument report = new CrystalReport1();
report.SetDataSource(dset);
reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
```

now im receiving 3 pages with supplier data and items in it. but i want to display 2 pages [1 page per supplier and items data relevant to each customer in each page ]

any idea what im doing wrong here? what should i do to achieve the output i needed.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean "1 page per supplier" (not "1 page per customer").
If my assumption is correct, you need to use "Report -> Group Expert" to group by `DataTable1.s_code` and then use the section expert to enable "New page before" for the group header.

Comment: yes, point 5 "New page after 1 visible record" means 1 page per each "item". Group expert is the right solution

Comment: fmunkert, it works, thanks a lot. one small problem though once i set "New page before" for the group header  first page comes as a blank

Comment: No idea this is the correct way but since first page is blank i added formula "Not OnFirstRecord" to the group header, "New page before"

Comment: If your report header is empty, make sure to suppress the report header section. Then, the first page will not be empty.